# How do I get a handle to the window that the user currently has open and is working in

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to get my program to monitor what windows are open on my computer. For now all I need is the applications name.

Using this code I only get the name of the terminal window in which I see the program output, switching and working in other windows does not cause output to change.

- I have tried sleeping between each log to see if I was missing the output for other windows, I still get the same result.
- I have tried running as administrator.

```cpp
int main() {

    HWND activeWindow = GetForegroundWindow();

    while (true) {
        if(activeWindow) {
            char windowText[256];
            GetWindowTextA(activeWindow, windowText, sizeof(windowText));

            std::cout << windowText << "\n";

        } else {
            std::cerr << "Found no active window" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You only get the foreground window once. If you want to track when it changes you need to get it inside the loop and compare against the last result to see if it changed.

Comment: @RetiredNinja. Thank you! That worked, I was simply never getting the window again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is actually pretty simple. If you put GetForegroundWindow in the loop it will actually update and give the required result.

Comment: A loop is the worst possible solution. It burns through an entire CPU while doing nothing useful, and can **still** miss a change in foreground activation. Use a [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/what-are-winevents) hook instead, and have the system notify you when events of interest happen.